# Как в Material UI добавлять динамично дочерние элементы?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, reactjs, material-ui

Мне нужно в Grid добавлять ссылки Link

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';


import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

class TournamentTable extends Component {

  render() {
    let content = [];
  
    const teamRender = () => {
      for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        let div = <Grid>Text</Grid>;
        for(let k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
          content.push(<Link href='#'>Link</Link>)
        }
      }

      return content
    };
    return (
      <>
        <Container>
   
          {
            teamRender()
          }
     
        </Container>

      </>
    );
  }
}
export default TournamentTable;
```

Получается у меня должно быть 3 Grid и в каждом по 2 Link. Покапался в доке Material UI , ничего не нашел про добавление дочерних элементов. Не понимаю как в Grid добавлять эти ссылки, чтобы потом уже Grid с ссылками мог пушить в массив и рендерить. Может кто-то знает, подскажет. Зараннее спасибо!